# Picking/filtering element from pandas table where data is between column header values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter

I have some 2D data that has boundaries (`bins`) like this:

```py
import numpy as npy
# These are the boundaries of our wind speeds and directions
speed_bins = npy.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 100.0])
dir_bins = npy.linspace(0,360,9)

# Random LPF values from 0–0.5
data = npy.random.rand(len(dir_bins)-1, len(speed_bins)-1)*0.5
dataTable = pd.DataFrame(LPF, index=dir_bins[1:],columns=speed_bins[1:])
```

I have some meteorological data like this:

```py
# Assume all arrays are the same length
speeds = numpy.array([...])
directions = numpy.array([...])
X = numpy.array([...])

metData = pd.DataFrame({'speeds':speeds,'directions':directions,'X':X})
```

What I need to do is find the element in `dataTable`, where each combination of `speed` and `direction` are bound.

I'm sure there is some pandas #magic that will do the following:

- For each `(speed, direction)` pair:

  - Find the row in `dataTable` that bounds the `speed`
  - Find the column in `dataTable` that bounds the `direction`
  - return the `data` variable.

**For example:** if my `speed` is `0.75` and my `direction` is `350` then I want to get the value at element `dataTable.iat[7,1]`. `0.75` is between `0.5` and `1.0` (the column header values) and similarly for the direction, but with the index values.

I hope I've described this well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Input data

The DataFrame for the boundaries:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# For reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)

# These are the boundaries of our wind speeds and directions
speed_bins = np.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0, 100.0])
dir_bins = np.linspace(0,360,9)

# Random LPF values from 0–0.5
data = np.random.rand(len(dir_bins)-1, len(speed_bins)-1)*0.5
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=dir_bins[1:],columns=speed_bins[1:])

print(df)
```

```
          0.5       1.0       2.0       5.0       10.0      100.0
45.0   0.274407  0.357595  0.301382  0.272442  0.211827  0.322947
90.0   0.218794  0.445887  0.481831  0.191721  0.395863  0.264447
135.0  0.284022  0.462798  0.035518  0.043565  0.010109  0.416310
180.0  0.389078  0.435006  0.489309  0.399579  0.230740  0.390265
225.0  0.059137  0.319961  0.071677  0.472334  0.260924  0.207331
270.0  0.132278  0.387117  0.228075  0.284217  0.009395  0.308818
315.0  0.306048  0.308467  0.471874  0.340910  0.179754  0.218516
360.0  0.348816  0.030113  0.333383  0.335319  0.105191  0.064463
```

---

The DataFrame for the meteorological data:

```py
# Randomly generate n many values for speeds and directions
n = 1000000

speeds     = np.random.rand(n) * 4
directions = np.random.rand(n) * 360

met_data = pd.DataFrame({'speeds': speeds, 
                         'directions': directions})

print(met_data.head(10))
```

```
     speeds  directions
0  1.261713  144.163960
1  1.454843  236.032725
2  2.280787  119.731554
3  1.754406  173.319830
4  3.953495   80.739232
5  0.408179  146.199108
6  0.835507  255.461460
7  0.645238   13.960304
8  2.612433   64.738510
9  1.013166  147.860518
```

---

##### Solution

The [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) function is especially useful to solve your problem. It can be used to assign the speed and direction values to the bin intervals you have defined.

```py
# Get the bin intervals that each of the speeds and directions lie in.
speed_intervals     = pd.cut(met_data['speeds'],     bins=[0] + df.columns.tolist())
direction_intervals = pd.cut(met_data['directions'], bins=[0] + df.index.tolist())

# Create a new DataFrame with these values as columns.
intervals = pd.concat([speed_intervals, direction_intervals], axis=1)

print(intervals.head(10))
```

```
       speeds      directions
0  (1.0, 2.0]  (135.0, 180.0]
1  (1.0, 2.0]  (225.0, 270.0]
2  (2.0, 5.0]   (90.0, 135.0]
3  (1.0, 2.0]  (135.0, 180.0]
4  (2.0, 5.0]    (45.0, 90.0]
5  (0.0, 0.5]  (135.0, 180.0]
6  (0.5, 1.0]  (225.0, 270.0]
7  (0.5, 1.0]     (0.0, 45.0]
8  (2.0, 5.0]    (45.0, 90.0]
9  (1.0, 2.0]  (135.0, 180.0]
```

---

From there, use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group this DataFrame by the (`speeds`, `directions`) combinations. Then for each group find the data value from the boundaries table, corresponding to the right limits of these combinations.

```py
# Create a copy of the met_data column
met_data2 = met_data.copy()

# Add a new column that will store the data boundary values
met_data['data'] = 0

# Grouping by the (speed, direction) combinations, iterate over each group.
for iv, g in intervals.groupby(['speeds', 'directions']):
    
    # Extract the right boundaries of the speed and direction combinations
    speed_limit = iv[0].right
    dir_limit = iv[1].right
    
    # From these boundaries extract the corresponding value in the data grid,
    #   and set it as the value of each the met_data row in the interval group. 
    met_data2.loc[g.index, 'values'] = df.at[dir_limit, speed_limit]

print(met_data2.head(10))
```

Final output:

```
     speeds  directions    values
0  1.261713  144.163960  0.489309
1  1.454843  236.032725  0.228075
2  2.280787  119.731554  0.043565
3  1.754406  173.319830  0.489309
4  3.953495   80.739232  0.191721
5  0.408179  146.199108  0.389078
6  0.835507  255.461460  0.387117
7  0.645238   13.960304  0.357595
8  2.612433   64.738510  0.191721
9  1.013166  147.860518  0.489309
```

---

#### Full code (as a generalised function):

```py
def get_data_values(data_table, mt_data, col_x='speeds', col_y='directions'):
    """
    From a given boundary table, extract all the values that corresponding to the bin positions
    of a pair of columns (each representing one of the table axes).
    """
    x_intervals = pd.cut(mt_data[col_x], bins=[0] + data_table.columns.tolist())
    y_intervals = pd.cut(mt_data[col_y], bins=[0] + data_table.index.tolist())
    
    intervals = pd.concat([x_intervals, y_intervals], axis=1)
    
    data = np.zeros(len(mt_data))
    
    for iv, g in intervals.groupby([col_x, col_y]):
        x_limit = iv[0].right
        y_limit = iv[1].right
        
        data[g.index] = data_table.at[y_limit, x_limit]
        
    return data
```

Usage:

```py
# Find the values from the boundary table where each of the (speed, direction) combinations fit in.
met_data['data'] = get_data_values(df, met_data, col_x='speeds', col_y='directions')
```

Comment: This was great. `cut`, `groupby` works well.